# ASP.NET/HTML: Use ASP.NET's label text/value in HTML's input value

Tags: asp.net, html, post, label

I have the following html codes (to be used in POST method):

```
// from Default.aspx
<input type="hidden" name="lblName" value="John" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="100.00" />
```

Is it possible to change the 'value' part by using the value/text ASP.NET label given below:

```
//from Default.aspx.cs
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="John" />
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="100.00" />
```

I just want to find a way to retrieve 'value' data dynamically coming from the ASP.NET label.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a server side hidden control whose values could be modified dynamically from the server side:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="lblName" runat="server" Value="John" />
```

Another possibility is to perform this on the client side using javascript: labels are usually rendered as `span` tags, so you will need to obtain the proper span by id and then assign it's `innerHTML` value to the hidden element. Using a javascript framework like jQuery might render this task much easier and guaranteed to work cross browser.

Comment: does the ID lblName the same as html input name? I'm trying to pass these values to a payment gateway.

Comment: Yes it is the same but ASP.NET could mangle the names and IDs of server side controls.